# Execute JavaScript with MVC3 RAZOR View Engine?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Index.cshtml Page in MVC3 Razor View Engine with Following Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<label id="lblClickMe" style="cursor:pointer"> Test Java Script Work in MVC Razor</label> || <label id="lblReset" style="cursor:pointer"> Rest    </label>

<br /><br /><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="txtResult"  style="width:300px"/>
```

And i have some JavaScript in Sane page Like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#lblClickMe").click(function () {

        var txtResukt = document.getElementById("txtResult");
        txtResukt.value = "Java script work successfully";

    })

    $("#lblReset").click(function () {

        var txtResukt = document.getElementById("txtResult");
        txtResukt.value = "";

    })
</script>
```

When I try to load my view give following exception from "lblClickMe" Click Event :

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

Any one fix this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#lblClickMe").click(function () {
         $("#txtResult").val("Java script work successfully");
        });
        $("#lblReset").click(function () {
          $("#txtResult").val("");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#lblClickMe").click(function () { 

        var txtResukt = document.getElementById("txtResult"); 
        txtResukt.value = "Java script work successfully"; 

    }) 

    $("#lblReset").click(function () { 

        var txtResukt = document.getElementById("txtResult"); 
        txtResukt.value = ""; 

    }) 

});
```

This ensures the HTML in the page is loaded first before code attempts to wire up the click events.

Comment: AnthonyWJones : i try you suggestion but full ready function give same exception.

Comment: @Mohammed: have you tried the browsers view source function ?  Does the html look right?  Have checked error console in the browser for parse errors of JavaScript? Are any referenced js files being delivered correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this?

```
$("#lblClickMe").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("txtResult").value = "Java script work successfully";
});
```

or in pure jQuery:

```
$("#lblClickMe").click(function () {
    $("#txtResult").val("Java script work successfully");
});
```